# Upgrade Zend Framework to utilize Zend_Http_UserAgent or is there another way for device detection?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mobile, upgrade

I maintain a site that is built using Zend Framework and it's at an old version 1.8.0.  I'm working on a mobile version of the site and would like to utilize Zend_Http_UserAgent, but I believe it's only available in the latest Zend Framework version 1.11.

I'm concerned that upgrading might introduce new issues.  Is there another simple way to perform device detection instead of using Zend_Http_UserAgent?  We're only supporting iPhone and iPad for our V1 launch, so it doesn't have to be anything overkill.

Also, what's the best practice when upgrading to the latest version of Zend Framework?  Is it as simple as overwriting the files at library/Zend?  I did that on my local environment and it shows I'm not at 1.11, but I'm not sure about the best way to detect if the upgrade might have introduced any new issues or broke anything other than walking the site and trying everything out manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unit tests! and tools like KDIFF, Beyond Compare,(or anything that can give you diffs of 2 different folders).

I keep my ZF in its own git repo, so i can generate diffs between versions to see whats changed, and then use some intuition too be smart about what those changes might have affected. You could go and view the SVN repo at Zend achieve the same effect.

Also - read the change-log - most obvious stuff will be in there and should help pinpoint what will definitely break you app or changes its behaviour.

In short how would test if any non zend code changes had affected your site? The apply those same actions when you upgrade Zend.

Comment: Cool, good advice.  Do you think it's best to upgrade to 1.11 just to utilize Zend_Http_UserAgent or try another device detection method?

Comment: Personally i'd go for the upgrade, as once that pain is out the way its pretty easy to setup (so i've been told)

Comment: Sounds good, I'll work on the upgrade.  I'm trying to get the PHP API for WURFL setup as described here - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html#zend.http.user-agent.quick-start - but I'm having issues.  Other threads look like there's different documentation if you're using version 1.3.1 of the wurfl php api.  I'll keep on digging!  Thanks!

Comment: Good enough for a upvote? or a correct answer? To add some further detail, the decision to upgrade also depends on how long you want to keep the project going? fixing bugs in old version of a framework is pain when you know they've been fixed in a newer version

Comment: Still new here, upvote since I liked the suggestion of upgrade vs trying to hack a custom solution.

Comment: Thanks, you'll also find it easier if you need to start hacking something up, to do so from the newest version of whatever library you are using as you tend to have less distance to travel between [library] ---> [hacky solution]